# Changing colour of a Line in Javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I have a rather trivial question regarding colouring of a line in javafx. I programmed a scene, in which a circle is created for every mouse click. Additionally after every mouse click a regression line is calculated and added. All I want to do now is change the colour of the regression line to red. I have tried the setFill(Color.[anycolour]) method, but to no avail. This is the code for the mouse click event.

```
    import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
    import javafx.event.EventHandler;
    import javafx.scene.Node;
    import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
    import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
    import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
    import javafx.scene.shape.Line;


    public class MouseClick implements EventHandler<MouseEvent>
    {
    private static int counter = 0;
    private static Line regression;
    
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) 
    {
        ObservableList<Node> children = Graphics.getRoot().getChildren();
        
        System.out.println("X: " + event.getX() + " Y: " + event.getY());

        Circle circle = new Circle(event.getX(), event.getY(), 5);
        children.add(circle);
        MouseClick.counter++;

        if(counter > 1)
        {
            children.remove(regression);
            double[] regr = calculateRegression(children);
            System.out.println("slope: " + regr[0]+ " Yint: " + regr[1]);

            regression = new Line();
            regression.setStartX(0.0);
            regression.setStartY(regr[1]);
            regression.setEndX(Graphics.getWidth());
            regression.setEndY(regr[0] * Graphics.getWidth() + regr[1]);
            regression.setFill(Color.CRIMSON);
            children.add(regression);
        }
    }
```

I have even tried to make a new class MyLine, where every Line is instantiated with a colour, but that also didn't work and the line remains black. Funnily enough it works for the circles, when I add that line of code after creating the circles.

```
    Circle circle = new Circle(event.getX(), event.getY(), 5);
    circle.setFill(Color.CRIMSON);
```

Does anyone know where the problem lies or if there is another way to change the line colour?

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Line` does not have an interior to fill. You need to set the color of the stroke instead. Replace:

```java
regression.setFill(Color.CRIMSON);
```

With:

```java
regression.setStroke(Color.CRIMSON);
```